# Whats is the best way to gather non-uniform chunks of a 1D array of a chosen MPI datatype?

Tags: arrays, mpi, chunks

Pi denotes an MPI process with rank i.
X and Y are 1D vectors that hold a chosen MPI_Datatype.
[aij] represents a sub-vector which may be of size 0.

For the vector X the index j in the sub-vector [aij] represents to which MPI process [aij] needs to be sent.

For the vector Y the index i in the sub-vector [aij] represents from which MPI process [aij] is to be received.

What is the best strategy to build Y from X?
A schematic diagram is shown below.

```
P1 X = {[a11],[a12],[a13],...,[a1n]};   Y = {[a11],[a21],[a31],...,[an1]};  
P2 X = {[a21],[a22],[a23],...,[a2n]};   Y = {[a12],[a22],[a32],...,[an2]};  
P3 X = {[a31],[a32],[a33],...,[a3n]};   Y = {[a13],[a23],[a33],...,[an3]};   
...                                                               
Pn X = {[an1],[an2],[an3],...,[ann]};   Y = {[a1n],[a2n],[a3n],...,[ann]};
```

The index numbering is chosen to start from one for convenience.

EDIT (following comments from eduffy and francis):
Currenty I am using point-to-point communications to do this operation when the virtual communication topology is sparse, i.e. when size([aij]) = 0 for the majority of the indices i,j.

1. Determine the number of receives NRECV each MPI process will get. This can be found for each process by an MPI_Reduce of the boolean FLAG = (i != j)&&(size([aij]) != 0).
2. Each process i executes non blocking sends of the chunks [aij] to process j if FLAG is true.
3. Each process i executes non blocking probe and receive of the non-zero size chunks [aji] from process j. These dynamic receives can be written as a loop of NRECV iterations.

However implementing this strategy in the MPI standards compliant way is getting difficult. For instance, a buffer can only be used in one communication at a time (even the apparently harmless case of multiple reads; source: Jeff Squyres [article](http://www.clustermonkey.net/MPI/mpi-the-top-ten-mistakes-to-avoid-part-2.html)).

UPDATE:

I find MPI_Alltoallv() suitable for the transposition of the sub-vectors [aij]. However, several articles (found in the the internet) do report scalability issues when the communication topology is sparse. Recent MPI standard (beyond version 3) includes the collective communication [MPI_Neighbor_alltoallv()](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Neighbor_alltoallv.html) on a communicator with a topology structure.

Comment: Have you looked at the `MPI_Gatherv` function?

Comment: This operation is a transposition. It is used by FFTW MPI to compute the Fast Fourier Transform of distributed multi dimensional arrays. See http://www.fftw.org/doc/Basic-distributed_002dtranspose-interface.html#Basic-distributed_002dtranspose-interface . You may take a look at the sources of FFTW-MPI to learn how it is performed ! A good starting point would be to use [`MPI_Alltoallv()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Alltoallv.html)

Comment: @eduffy: Yes, I am studying the MPI_Gatherv option. I have edited the question explaining my current approach.

Comment: @francis: Thank you for pointing out the FFTW MPI links and MPI_Alltoallv(). I will take a look. I did not tag the transpose keyword as it is not a transpose in the strict sense.